# `mu4e-contexts` multiple gmail accounts using incorrect smtp credentials

Tags: email, mu4e, smtpmail

I'm attempting to set up multiple Gmail accounts using `mu4e-context`'s. I have a lot of the features working except one. I can switch between contexts, update my mail in each account (using offlineimap) and I can send mail.

The problem is that I have multiple lines in my `.authinfo` file, that have the same hostname - I was assuming that `mu4e` would be able to differentiate by username, this appears to not be the case. It doesn't matter which context I am in, the mail is always being sent from the account that is configured *first* in the `.authinfo` file.

I don't know how to make each context use separate credentials for logging into the Gmail SMTP Server.

I thought about attempting to set up some hostname aliases so that `personal.gmail.com` and `work.gmail.com` both resolve to `smtp.gmail.com` so that I can give them separate machine names in `authinfo`, but I am unsure how to achieve this (on OSX) or even if it's a sensible way to solve this problem (Ideally I'd not have to monkey around with config outside of Emacs).

My authinfo looks like this

```
machine smtp.gmail.com login personal@example.com port 587 password fakepassword
machine smtp.gmail.com login work@example.com port 587 password fakepassword
```

and the relevant parts of my mu4e-config is:

```
(setq mu4e-get-mail-command "offlineimap")
(setq mail-user-agent 'mu4e-user-agent)
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it)

(setq smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls)
(setq smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
(setq smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
(setq smtpmail-smtp-service 587)

(setq mu4e-contexts
      `( ,(make-mu4e-context
           :name "personal"
           :enter-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Switch to Personal context"))
           ;; leave-func not defined
           :match-func (lambda (msg)
                         (when msg
                           (mu4e-message-contact-field-matches msg :to "personal@example.com")))
           :vars '(  (user-mail-address . "personal@example.com"  )
                     (mu4e-drafts-folder . "/personal/drafts")
                     (mu4e-sent-folder   . "/personal/sent")
                     (mu4e-trash-folder  . "/personal/bin")
                     (mu4e-maildir-shortcuts . (("/personal/INBOX" . ?i)
                                                ("/personal/sent"  . ?s)
                                                ("/personal/bin"   . ?t)))
                     (smtpmail-mail-address . "personal@example.com")
                     (user-full-name    . "Matt Valentine-House" )))
         ,(make-mu4e-context
           :name "work"
           :enter-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Switch to Work context"))
           ;; leave-fun not defined
           :match-func (lambda (msg)
                         (when msg
                           (mu4e-message-contact-field-matches msg :to "work@example.com")))
           :vars '(  (user-mail-address . "work@example.com" )
                     (mu4e-drafts-folder . "/work/drafts")
                     (mu4e-sent-folder   . "/work/sent")
                     (mu4e-trash-folder  . "/work/bin")
                     (mu4e-maildir-shortcuts . (("/work/INBOX" . ?i)
                                                ("/work/sent"  . ?s)
                                                ("/work/bin"   . ?t)))
                     (smtpmail-mail-address . "work@example.com")
                     ( user-full-name    . "Matthew Valentine-House" )))))
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

It's been almost two years since the question was asked, but I have just had the same problem and I managed to solve it using the `smtpmail-smtp-user` variable. [In the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/smtpmail/Authentication.html) it says:

> If the variable smtpmail-smtp-user is set to a non-nil value, then only entries for that user are considered.

In my personal context vars I have:

```
(smtpmail-smtp-user . "personal@example.com")
```

In my work context vars I have:

```
(smtpmail-smtp-user . "work@example.com")
```

I've only tested it briefly, but it seems to work properly.